# SQL ARRAY: Select ID from my_table where "arrayvalue" = "defined_arrayvalue"

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, select, spatial

This is a beginner-question relating arrays. I hope the answer is simple.
The example is taken from Oracle Spatial, but I think it is valid for all arrays.

I have this SELECT:

```
SELECT
    D.FID
  , D.GEOM.SDO_ELEM_INFO   -- column GEOM contains spatial data
FROM
    my_table D
```

I get this result:

```
73035   MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1)
73036   MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 11, 2, 2, 19, 2, 1)
73037   MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1)
```

Now I want to SELECT all rows where (1,2,1) is defined:

```
SELECT
    D.FID
  , D.GEOM.SDO_ELEM_INFO
FROM
    my_table D
WHERE
-- Pseudo-Code is following
    D.GEOM.SDO_ELEM_INFO is "(1, 2, 1)";
```

So, in simple words: "array_from_row = defined_array". 
I found a lot about IMPLODE and TABLE and COLLECT etc. But how to define a clause on two arrays?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try IN clause, you can also use both

```
SELECT
    D.FID
  , D.GEOM.SDO_ELEM_INFO
  FROM
 my_table D
 WHERE
 D.GEOM.SDO_ELEM_INFO in (1, 2, 1) or ( D.GEOM.SDO_ELEM_INFO = 1 or D.GEOM.SDO_ELEM_INFO = 2 or D.GEOM.SDO_ELEM_INFO = 3);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I does not work:
`ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"`

Comment: Remove the single quotes in the query. Edited the answer, please use it

Comment: `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"`